# Vertically And Horizontally centering an Image using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, frontend, alignment, center

**Hey, I'm using bootstrap for one of my projects, and I want to center my image both vertically and horizontally with it being responsive, What should I do??
I was trying to make a responsive front end page that looks like google
But i want it to be in the very center of the screen, and it being responsive as well..

And The image I'm talking about is inserted using this

```
<img src="google.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Google" id="Logo">
```

Comment: as soon as you start with `vertical center` you should start using `Flexbox`...

Comment: could you specify a bit

Comment: search for flex and how to cenetr vertically and horizontally. Plenty duplicate questions even here on SO. Its a daily question that is at least asked once per day here. Look for those duplciates, read into it and ask again after your attempt. If you then still need help, state where exactly you get stuck.

Answer (score -2):

Hi bro uo must use flex for that you can search flex in bootstrap doc it explains how to use flex

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/